# Nvidia Drivers in Asus m50VC GeForce9300M Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, xorg

I've installed ubuntu 13.04 in my Asus M50VC and I have some problems with nvidia crashes and compiz errors.
It presents lots of drivers by nvidia with 313 update, 310 update and the latest update was 304 update to nvidia. Ihave tried the most recent drivers and now I'm confused that ubuntu gets an older update after installed more recent nvidia updates.
Should I stop using nvidia drivers and use the XORG driver?

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem with ASUS M50VM. After update of nvidia-current-updates from 304.88-0ubuntu0.0.1 to 304.108-0ubuntu0.0.1 the ubuntu 12.04 did not load gnome.

Downgrading to nvidia-current-updates=304.88-0ubuntu0.0.1 helped.

However now I have to skip update of nvidia-current-updates every time I run update manager.

Comment: Could you please provide the full command to execute to do the downgrade?